# How to show loop data from orders only having created_at != updated_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to show the response time, which I have set up but it currently shows the response time with all orders into account, so it's not accurate.

For example, there are 3 orders by buyers and a seller takes 2 days to respond to 1 of those orders, i want it to say 2 days.  Instead of taking all 3 orders into account and saying .66 days.

Here's the controller for the page its displayed on:

```
    @orders = Order.all.where(seller: current_user).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15) || @orders = Order.all.where(seller: current_buyer).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)

    @orders_a = Order.all.where(seller: current_user) || @orders = Order.all.where(seller: current_buyer)
    @orders_month = @orders_a.all.group_by { |mon|  mon.created_at.beginning_of_month }
    @orders_day = @orders_a.all.group_by { |day|  day.created_at.beginning_of_day }


    @order = Order.new
```

The @orders_month and @orders_day are the ones displaying the information.  (It is both charted and graphed in a table)

Here's the view:

```
  <% @orders_month.each do |month, orders| %>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td><%= month.strftime("%B") %></td>
             <td class="center"><%= orders.count %></td>
             <td class="center"><%= (orders.sum { |order| order.updated_at.day - order.created_at.day } / orders.count ) %> Days</td>
             </td>
   <% end %>
```

I have tried adding attempts like and similar to the following with no avail:
if order.updated_at != order.created_at

Comment: `.where("created_at <> updated_at")`?

Comment: thanks.. to clarify, in the controller try this?

Comment: Yes - I didn't have the time to make a complete example earlier though.

Comment: Yeah can you show me an example, I'm a bit mixed on exactly what to do? like this? @ orders_a = Order.all.where(seller: current_user).where("created_at <> updated_at") or @ orders_a = Order.all.where(seller: current_user && created_at <> updated_at) ? something along those lines or .. something else?

Comment: okay it works but i realized its not how i expected, well, how i want it.  is there a way to do it primarily through the views loop? Because i want the table to display total orders and response time of orders with created <> updated but if i do it through the controller then the total orders only display orders of ones with differences in created and updated times..